# SqlServer stored procedure called from php doesn't return integer output correctly

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, output

I am trying to capture out put from a stored procedure on a SQL server 2008 database using php mssql functions.  The code runs iwthout errors, but I am getting a weird vlaue returned for one of my output parameters.

The stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[check_barcode_and_return]
    @Barcode nvarchar(20),
    @IsInDatabase int OUTPUT,
    @Product_Info nvarchar(100) OUTPUT

AS
  SELECT @IsInDatabase = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.product_info WHERE barcode = @Barcode

  DECLARE @Brand varchar(45)
  SET @Brand = (SELECT brand FROM dbo.product_info WHERE barcode = @Barcode)
  DECLARE @Description varchar(50)
  SET @Description = (SELECT product_desc FROM dbo.product_info WHERE barcode = @Barcode) 
  SELECT @Product_Info = @Brand + '_' + @Description
RETURN 

GO
```

Here is the php code that calls it:

```
<?php
  // use a barcode known to be present in database
  $barcode_yes = '11335577';
  // use a sbarcode known NOT to be in database
  $barcode_no = '0011223344';
  $host = '00.000.000.000';
  $db = 'dbName';
  $user = 'username';
  $password = 'password';
  $barcodeInDB = 0;
  $productInfo = "";
  try {
    $conn = mssql_connect($host, $user, $password);
    mssql_select_db($db, $conn);
    $stmt = mssql_init('check_barcode_and_return', $conn);
    mssql_bind($stmt, '@Barcode', $barcode_yes, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 20);
    mssql_bind($stmt, '@IsInDatabase', $barcodeInDB, SQLINT1, true, false, 1);
    mssql_bind($stmt, '@Product_Info', $productInfo, SQLVARCHAR, true, false, 100);
    mssql_execute($stmt, true);
    echo 'positive test results:'."\n";
    echo 'output $barcodeInDB = '.$barcodeInDB."\n";
    echo '$productInfo = '.$sampleInfo."\n";

    //reset for next call
    mssql_free_statement($stmt);
    $barcodeInDB = 0;
    $productInfo = "";

    $stmt = mssql_init('check_barcode_and_return', $conn);
    mssql_bind($stmt, '@Barcode', $barcode_no, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 20);
    mssql_bind($stmt, '@IsInDatabase', $barcodeInDB, SQLINT1, true, false, 1);
    mssql_bind($stmt, '@Product_Info', $productInfo, SQLVARCHAR, true, false, 100);
    mssql_execute($stmt, true);
    echo 'negative test results:'."\n";
    echo 'output $barcodeInTable = '.$barcodeInDB."\n";
    echo '$productInfo = '.$productInfo."\n";

    mssql_close($conn);
  } 
  catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

When I run this from the command line, this is the result:

```
positive test results:
output $barcodeInDB = 968529665
$productInfo = Heinz_tomato ketchup
negative test results:
output $barcodeInTable = 968529664
$productInfo = _
```

If I run the stored procedure directly using SQL Server Management Studio, entering the barcodes used above, I get **@BarcodeInDB = 1** for the positive test and **@BarcodeInDB = 0** for the negative one.

The code is on an Linux server running **Ubuntu with php5.3.10**.

What do I need to change to get the correct value for the integer output parameter?

Comment: Is there any chance you can run it on a webpage and check the results? If the webpage shows the correct output, it may have something to do with your php.ini file in your php5/cli folder.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Just tried that and still getting the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integer data type in I needed to bind my output parameter as a SQLINT4 because apparently, T-SQL integer variables are 4-byte integers.  Trying to force them into a datatype with smaller capacity (i.e. SQLINT1, SQLINT2 or SQLBIT) results in the unpredictable output.

So, I changed to...

```
...
mssql_bind($stmt, '@IsInDatabase', $barcodeInDB, SQLINT4, true);
...
```

and it worked fine.